# Bold Text is not coming for a small document

Tags: bold

I have a small latex document of one page. The problem is `\textbf{}` does not make the text bold. There is no error but bold text is not appearing. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{twentysecondcv} % a4paper for A4

\begin{document}

\section{Education}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
    \twentyitem{2008-2016}{\textbf{Ph.D. in Computer Science} {\normalfont}}{}{\emph{Spezialisation in Analytics \& Machine Learning}}
    \twentyitem{2003-2006}{\textbf{MCA}}{}{Majoring in Computer Science}
    \twentyitem{2000-2003}{\textbf{BCA}}{}{Majoring in Computer Science}
\end{twenty}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the class file (`twentysecondcv.cls`)?

Comment: Hi, Here is the link: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv

Comment: The class does `\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\color{gray}}`, so what you get is the expected result: instead of boldface, the normal font in gray color is used.

Answer (score 1):

The class file does

```
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\color{gray}}
```

so what you get is the expected result. The color is defined by

```
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
```

It's not clear what the purpose of such definition is, but probably the author wanted to use grayscale for headings and such things. Of course this is the *wrong* approach. It's the risk when using templates made by others: you also get their programming errors.

Solution: forget about that template. If you still want to use it, restore the default definition of `\bfseries`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{twentysecondcv} % a4paper for A4

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bfseries}{%
  \not@math@alphabet\bfseries\mathbf
  \fontseries\bfdefault\selectfont
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Education}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
\twentyitem{2008-2016}
  {\textbf{Ph.D. in Computer Science}}
  {}
  {\emph{Spezialisation in Analytics \& Machine Learning}}

\twentyitem{2003-2006}
  {\textbf{MCA}}
  {}
  {Majoring in Computer Science}

\twentyitem{2000-2003}
  {\textbf{BCA}}
  {}
  {Majoring in Computer Science}
\end{twenty}

\end{document}
```

[image]